# Java list in GUI

Tags: java, list, user-interface, netbeans

I have added a list to my GUI using Netbeans (using the GUI editor) and added three values: Red, green and blue.
I want to change the brightness of the image the user chooses from the list, i.e. if the user selects green in the list and then presses the increase brightness button, the brightness will only increase of the green image.
Ive added a list selection event, following the instructions here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html

My code for the event is the following:

```
private void jList1ValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                    
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        jList1.getSelectedIndex();
        if (jList1.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
            int listInt = 1;
        }
        if (jList1.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {
            int listInt = 2;
        }
        if (jList1.getSelectedIndex() == 2) {
            int listInt = 3;
        }
    }
```

And my code for the brightness button is the following:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        System.out.println(listInt);
        if (listInt == 1) {
            increaseContrast(redImage);
            update(redImage, redIcon, redLabel);
        }
        if (listInt == 2) {
            increaseContrast(greenImage);
            update(greenImage, greenIcon, greenLabel);
        }
        if (listInt == 3) {
            increaseContrast(blueImage);
            update(blueImage, blueIcon, blueLabel);
        }
```

A 0 is always printed to the terminal regardless of what the selection is, which must mean the first code segment isnt working. Can anyone help with why this is happening?

Comment: Not relevant but still useful: don't use a GUI builder.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are declaring and modifying local variables `listInt` inside that `jList1ValueChanged` method, which go out of scope when you exit that function. Surely you wanted to change an instance variable that is also visible for `jButton2ActionPerformed` (probably called `listInt`) but just set its value in those `if` statements, as opposed to declaring a local variable with the same name. You are getting 0 because that's the default initialization value for int (and so `listInt`).

Comment: You're absolutely right, stupid mistake but thank you!